# R linear regression on a dataframe of variable length

Tags: r

I can perform a linear regression on a dataframe of known length where y is the first column followed by the x variables:

```
a <-rnorm(20)
b <-rnorm(20)
c <-rnorm(20)
d <-rnorm(20)
e <-rnorm(20)
f <-rnorm(20)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f)
df


dlm <- lm(df[,c(1)]~df[,c(2)]+df[,c(3)]+df[,c(4)]+df[,c(5)])
dlm
```

However when dealing with many dataframes of variable column length (first column: y variable,other columns x variables), I tried:

```
dlm2 <- lm(df[,c(1)]~df[,c(-1)])
dlm2
```

but this did not work.
I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: @MrFlick Make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax in this case would be

```
lm(a~., df)
```

the problem with your attempt is that `df[,-1]` is a a data.frame (which is a list object). If you wanted that to work you just need to convert to a matrix

```
lm( df[,1] ~ as.matrix(df[,-1]) )
```

but this really isn't an efficient use of the formula syntax.

Answer (score 2):

This solves the problem in an efficient manner:

```
lm(formula(df))
```